# FullCalendar display on localhost but not on server

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

I'm currently building a rails app and I need a calendar to display some events so I decided to use FullCalendar.

The calendar works fine on localhost but when I deploy my app on a server, the calendar won't display anymore! I figured out that I have a Javascript error which is not there on localhost.

> TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...$('#calendar').fullCalendar...')

It seems to be the `fullCalendar()` which is not find when the page is load.

I have done some research but I didn't find anything. Does anyone ever encountered this issues and know how to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: check the console for errors. also check the network tab to see if your fullcalendar.js loads properly. if not either the path to the file is wrong/different on the server or the permissions are set wrong

Comment: As john has mentioned, please check whether the fullcalendar js has loaded properly or not, and the JS file should be loaded before this js function is invoked.

Comment: As others have said, most likely the fullCalendar script files either didn't deploy or the URL pointing to them is wrong in your page. Check your network tools to see where it's trying to retrieve the script file from, and what response is being returned by the server when it makes the call.

Answer (score 0):

Did you need to rebuild your assets pipeline using rake assets:clean and rake assets:precompile? Don't know if anyone else has observed this behavior, it may be specific to my installation, but whenever I run a rake assets command I have to check the file permissions in my project directory because one or two will have their values changed from 755 to 600 (assuming linux environment). The errors that result are not very helpful in identifying this!